# How to properly reload associations after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

After destroying an object we must return json containing object's former associations without it, e.g. after deleting a post we need to return a list of updated categories where each one of them has deleted post removed from 'post_ids' attribute.

Problem is that I have ~5 of such associations and making 5 queries to reload all of them per each delete request does not seem right. What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Here's a simplified version of my current code. Let's say I have two models

```
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
   end

   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

     def as_json(options = {})
       options[:methods] = [:post_ids]
     end
   end
```

A controller

```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController

     respond_to :json

     def destroy
       @post = Post.find(params[:id]
       category_ids = @post.category_ids
       if @post.destroy
         @categories = Category.find(category_ids)
         render :destroy
       end
     end

   end
```

And a rabl template, that basically returns @categories as json

```
   object false
   node(:categories) { @categories.map(&:as_json) }
```

Comment: If you've got 5 different associations all modelled as separate tables I don't see how you're going to beat doing 5 different queries. The only way you might be able to improve it is if the 5 other models were subclasses using single table inheritance.

You might be able to DRY up your code a bit but in terms of querying efficiency I can't see an improvement on what you've got.

Comment: @Shadwell thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately STI is not an option since all five models are completely different. I was thinking about something like eager loading all associations, then disabling caching somehow, so that I won't need to reload them from database — they ought to be in memory somewhere)